# Type of kernel being produced

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to understand the MATLAB implementation of non-local means filtering algorithm from [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13176-non-local-means-filter). I want to understand what kind of kernel the following portion of code is producing:

```
kernel=zeros(2*f+1,2*f+1);   
for d=1:f    
  value= 1 / (2*d+1)^2 ;    
  for i=-d:d
      for j=-d:d
          kernel(f+1-i,f+1-j)= kernel(f+1-i,f+1-j) + value ;
      end
  end
end
kernel = kernel ./ f;
```

I tried to look at the intermediate outputs and I think it's producing a Gaussian weighted kernel but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Output :

```
kernel =

0.0200    0.0200    0.0200    0.0200    0.0200
0.0200    0.0756    0.0756    0.0756    0.0200
0.0200    0.0756    0.0756    0.0756    0.0200
0.0200    0.0756    0.0756    0.0756    0.0200
0.0200    0.0200    0.0200    0.0200    0.0200
```

Paper referred : [Buades-NonLocal](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT6150/Articles/Buades-NonLocal.pdf) Section 3

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I believe Cris' answer addresses the problem much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buades et al. definitely intended to use Gaussian weights. This kernel, if it is intended to be an approximation, yields a very rough approximation. This is what it looks like in 1D for `f=3`, `f=10` and `f=100`:

[image: kernels]

I have added a Gaussian kernel for comparison. Furthermore, the Gaussian is perfectly isotropic, whereas this approximation is far from it (because it is build up of squares).

And I find this weird, because the four nested loops of the NL-means algorithm where it is used is not made any faster by using this approximation over a true Gaussian. The square of the patch difference is multiplied by the kernel, the cost of this operation is independent of how the kernel is generated or what values it contains.

My suggestion would be to replace `make_kernel` by something like this, which creates a true 2D Gaussian kernel:

```
function kernel = make_kernel2(f)
x = linspace(-2,2,2*f+1);
kernel = exp(-0.5*x.^2);
kernel = kernel .* kernel.'; % requires newer MATLAB, otherwise use bsxfun
kernel = kernel / sum(kernel(:));
```

---

I have never seen this particular approximation to the Gaussian before (and I have seen a lot). Typically, a Gaussian convolution is approximated by repeated applications of a convolution with a box kernel (they say 3x is enough for a fairly good approximation, [but more are needed if the derivative is to be computed after](https://www.peterkovesi.com/papers/FastGaussianSmoothing.pdf)). The downside to this approach is that is is not possible to re-use the integral image, since each convolution is applied to a different image (i.e. the result of the previous convolution). A convolution with a box kernel can be computed using the integral image, where the output for one pixel can be computed by addition of 4 values, plus one division, no matter what the size of the box is.

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
out = imfilter(img,ones(3,3)/9);
out = imfilter(out,ones(3,3)/9);
out = imfilter(out,ones(3,3)/9);
```

If, instead of applying the box convolution repeatedly, one computes several box convolutions of different sizes, all using the same integral image, and adds the results together, then one obtains a convolution with the kernel asked about in this question. This would be a rough approximation to a Gaussian, and not isotropic, but it would be *very* cheap to compute. (The demo code below doesn't use an integral image, this is not meant to demonstrate timing, just what the result looks like.)

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
out = imfilter(img,ones(3,3)/9) / 3;
out = out + imfilter(img,ones(4,4)/16) / 3;
out = out + imfilter(img,ones(5,5)/25) / 3;
```

I bet that this is where this kernel comes from. However, by creating this kernel, rather than applying the various convolutions separately and adding the results, all of the speed benefits of this method are not used, leaving only the many negative aspects of it.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the innermost two loops are a non-vectorized way to define a `(2d+1) x (2d+1)`-sized constant matrix that sums to 1 (`value` is merely the reciprocal of `1*(2*d+1)^2`). This defines [a box blur kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur).

So what happens is that a `(2f+1) x (2f+1)` kernel is defined by summing up concentric box blur kernels of size `3 x 3`, `5 x 5`, ..., `(2f+1) x (2f+1)`. Since convolution is a linear operation, the sum of box blurs will be applied separately, and the convex combination of individual kernels is a valid kernel.

While box blurs can be used to approximate a Gaussian blur by being used recursively, a convex combination such as the one above will likely behave differently (as noted by [Cris Luengo in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571689/type-of-kernel-being-produced/52571971#comment92081038_52571971)). Even the symmetry is off: a Gaussian kernel is spherically symmetric, while these box kernels have corners.

In conclusion, I believe the answer to your question is "no", it probably doesn't approximate a Gaussian kernel, but it's still a blur kernel.

---

If I had to create the above kernel I'd vectorize it:

```
kernel = zeros(2*f+1,2*f+1);   
for d=1:f
    kernel(f+1-d:f+1+d,f+1-d:f+1+d) = kernel(f+1-d:f+1+d,f+1-d:f+1+d) + 1/(2*d+1)^2;
end
kernel = kernel / f;
```

Comment: Convolution of a series of box kernels is an approximation to a Gaussian, not their addition. f * b * b * b * ... = f * g (f is image, b is box, g is Gaussian). This is not the same as f * (b + b + b + ...).

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I know, mostly because of the central limit theorem. I figured that the quote from wiki is true in a broader sense, but reading it again it probably isn't. I figured a blur is a blur ;) Do you know of a specific name for this kernel beyond "multiple box blur kernels"?

Comment: @CrisLuengo also the referenced paper only seems to mention Gaussian kernels, so I figured this simpler construction is used as a drop-in.

Comment: I have not seen this kernel construction before. It looks to be something with long tails, meaning that central pixels are weighted more heavily than with a Gaussian kernel.

Comment: Though I might be wrong. I’ll have to generate one of these for large parameter `f`, see what it looks like. But considering the Gaussian is separable, I don’t see how this approximation would be any cheaper. Plus, it’s replacing something perfectly isotopic with something square...

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I edited the conclusion in order to not lie. Also: isn't a Gaussian kernel spherically symmetric? The above kernel would then definitely behave differently around the corners. Edit: your edit made the same point ;)